# How to normalize in FFTW in 2 or more dimensions?

Tags: fortran, fft, fftw

I'm trying to figure out how to properly normalize the results of a DFT using FFTW. The [FFTW tutorial](http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/The-1d-Real_002ddata-DFT.html#The-1d-Real_002ddata-DFT) states that the forward (FFTW_FORWARD) discrete Fourier transform of a 1d complex array X of size n computes an array Y, where

Y_k = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1} X_j e^{-2\pi j k \sqrt{-1}/n}

The backward  DFT computes:

Y_k = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{n-1} X_j e^{+2\pi j k \sqrt{-1}/n}

These definitions are the same as for real-to-complex transformations.

Furthermore, the tutorial specifies that "FFTW computes an unnormalized transform, in that there is no coefficient in front of the summation in the DFT. In other words, applying the forward and then the backward transform will multiply the input by n." **However, it doesn't specify where exactly this re-scaling needs to be done.** I suppose this may be application dependant, but am not sure how to use it properly. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4856046/6168231) states that it should be normalized in the forward direction, but I have my doubts, which I will elaborate.

My goal is to figure out how to properly normalize the FFT results in order to get what I expect. So I did a simple 1D transformation first, where I know what to expect exactly: Using the same convention as FFTW (normalisation factor=1, oscillatory factor=-2*pi for the forward fourier transform), when I transform

1/2 (δ(1 + x) - δ(1 - x))

with δ being the dirac delta function, I expect to get:

integral_(-∞)^∞ (1/2 (δ(1 + x) - δ(1 - x))) e^(-2 π i ω x) dx = i sin(2π  ω)

the same holds for when I do an IFFT on i sin(2π  ω), only now I need to normalize by dividing by n.

Here is the code I use to demonstrate this behaviour:

```
program use_fftw

  use,intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  include 'fftw3.f03'


  integer, parameter   :: N = 1000
  integer, parameter   :: dp = kind(1.d0)
  real(dp), parameter  :: pi = 3.1415926d0
  real(dp), parameter  :: physical_length = 500
  real(dp), parameter  :: dx = physical_length/real(N)
  real(dp), parameter  :: dk = 1.d0 / physical_length

  integer :: i, ind1, ind2


  ! for double precision: use double complex & call dfftw_plan_dft_1d
  complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX), allocatable, dimension(:) :: arr_out
  real(C_DOUBLE),    allocatable, dimension(:)         :: arr_in
  type(C_PTR)                                          :: plan_forward, plan_backward


  allocate(arr_in(1:N))
  allocate(arr_out(1:N/2+1))

  plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_1d(N, arr_in, arr_out, FFTW_ESTIMATE)
  plan_backward = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_1d(N, arr_out, arr_in, FFTW_ESTIMATE)


  !----------------------
  ! Setup
  !----------------------

  ! add +1: index = 1 corresponds to x=0
  ind1 = int(1.d0/dx)+1                   ! index where x=1
  ind2 = int((physical_length-1.d0)/dx)+1 ! index where x=-1

  arr_in = 0
  arr_in(ind1) = -0.5d0
  arr_in(ind2) = 0.5d0


  !----------------------
  ! Forward
  !----------------------
  call fftw_execute_dft_r2c(plan_forward, arr_in, arr_out)

  write(*,*) "Verification: Max real part of arr_out:", maxval(real(arr_out))

  open(unit=666,file='./fftw_output_norm1d_fft.txt', form='formatted')
  do i = 1, N/2+1
    write(666, '(2E14.5,x)') (i-1)*dk, aimag(arr_out(i))
  enddo
  close(666)

  write(*,*) "Finished! Written results to fftw_output_norm1d_fft.txt"


  !----------------------
  ! Backward
  !----------------------
  call fftw_execute_dft_c2r(plan_backward, arr_out, arr_in)

  arr_in = arr_in/N

  open(unit=666,file='./fftw_output_norm1d_real.txt', form='formatted')
  do i = 1, N
    write(666, '(2E14.5,x)') (i-1)*dx, arr_in(i)
  enddo
  close(666)

  write(*,*) "Finished! Written results to fftw_output_norm1d_real.txt"

  deallocate(arr_in, arr_out)
  call fftw_destroy_plan(plan_forward)
  call fftw_destroy_plan(plan_backward)

end program use_fftw
```

And the results, perfectly according to what I'd expect:

[image: Result of Fourier transform]
[image: Result of Inverse Transform of Fourier transform]

So in this case, I only normalized (division by n) when going from Fourier space back to real space and obtained what I wanted.

But [I ran into problems](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/50007/correctly-scaling-power-spectrum-and-correlation-function-of-galaxies-from-mock) when I tried to do the same for multiple dimensions.
This time, I'm trying to transform

sqrt(π/2) ((δ(-1 + x) - δ(1 + x)) δ(y) + δ(x) (δ(-1 + y) - δ(1 + y)))

which should give

integral_(-∞)^∞ (sqrt(π/2) ((δ(-1 + x) - δ(1 + x)) δ(y) + δ(x) (δ(-1 + y) - δ(1 + y)))) e^(-2 π i {x, y} {a, b}) d{x, y}  =  +i sin(a) + i sin(b)

I plot the results for x=0 (k_x = 0, respectively):
[image: Fourier transform 2d]

which seems completely wrong, both in frequency of the sinus wave and the amplitude.

However, transforming back and normalising by dividing by n^2 gives the expected initial conditions, in both x and y direction. Here is the plot for x=0:
[image: inverted fourier transform]

I have no idea what I am doing wrong...

Here is the 2d code:

```
program use_fftw

  use,intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
  implicit none
  include 'fftw3.f03'


  integer, parameter   :: N = 1000
  integer, parameter   :: dp = kind(1.d0)
  real(dp), parameter  :: pi = 3.1415926d0
  real(dp), parameter  :: physical_length = 500
  real(dp), parameter  :: dx = physical_length/real(N)
  real(dp), parameter  :: dk = 1.d0 / physical_length

  integer :: i, ind1, ind2


  ! for double precision: use double complex & call dfftw_plan_dft_1d
  complex(C_DOUBLE_COMPLEX),  allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: arr_out
  real(C_DOUBLE),             allocatable, dimension(:,:) :: arr_in
  type(C_PTR)                              :: plan_forward, plan_backward


  allocate(arr_in(1:N, 1:N))
  allocate(arr_out(1:N/2+1, 1:N))


  plan_forward = fftw_plan_dft_r2c_2d(N, N, arr_in, arr_out, FFTW_ESTIMATE)
  plan_backward = fftw_plan_dft_c2r_2d(N, N, arr_out, arr_in, FFTW_ESTIMATE)


  !----------------------
  ! Setup
  !----------------------

  ! add +1: index = 1 corresponds to x=0
  ind1 = int(1.d0/dx)+1                     ! get index where x = 1
  ind2 = int((physical_length-1.d0)/dx)+1   ! get index where x = -1

  arr_in = 0
  ! y=0:
  arr_in(ind1, 1) =  sqrt(pi/2)
  arr_in(ind2, 1) =  -sqrt(pi/2)
  ! x=0:
  arr_in(1, ind1) =  sqrt(pi/2)
  arr_in(1, ind2) =  -sqrt(pi/2)


  !----------------------
  ! Forward
  !----------------------
  call fftw_execute_dft_r2c(plan_forward, arr_in, arr_out)

  write(*,*) "Verification: Max real part of arr_out:", maxval(real(arr_out))

  open(unit=666,file='./fftw_output_norm2d_fft_x=0.txt', form='formatted')
  open(unit=667,file='./fftw_output_norm2d_fft_y=0.txt', form='formatted')
  do i = 1, N
    write(666, '(2E14.5,x)') (i-1)*dk, aimag(arr_out(1,i))
  enddo
  do i = 1, N/2+1
    write(667, '(2E14.5,x)') (i-1)*dk, aimag(arr_out(i,1))
  enddo
  close(666)
  close(667)

  write(*,*) "Finished! Written results to fftw_output_normalisation_fft_x.txt and fftw_output_normalisation_fft_y.txt"


  !----------------------
  ! Backward
  !----------------------
  call fftw_execute_dft_c2r(plan_backward, arr_out, arr_in)

  ! Normalisation happens here!
  arr_in = arr_in/N**2

  open(unit=666,file='./fftw_output_norm2d_real_x=0.txt', form='formatted')
  open(unit=667,file='./fftw_output_norm2d_real_y=0.txt', form='formatted')
  do i = 1, N
    write(666, '(2E14.5,x)') (i-1)*dx, arr_in(1, i)
    write(667, '(2E14.5,x)') (i-1)*dx, arr_in(i, 1)
  enddo
  close(666)
  close(667)

  write(*,*) "Finished! Written results to fftw_output_norm2d_real_x=0.txt and fftw_output_norm2d_real_y=0.txt"

  deallocate(arr_in, arr_out)
  call fftw_destroy_plan(plan_forward)
  call fftw_destroy_plan( plan_backward)

end program use_fftw
```

and a python plotting tool:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

#====================================
# Plots the results of the FFTW
# example programs.
#====================================

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sys import argv
from time import sleep

errormessage="""
I require an argument: Which output file to plot.
Usage: ./plot_fftw.py <case>
options for case:
    1   fftw_output_norm1d_fft.txt
    2   fftw_output_norm1d_real.txt
    3   fftw_output_norm2d_fft_x=0.txt
    4   fftw_output_norm2d_real_x=0.txt
    5   fftw_output_norm2d_fft_y=0.txt
    6   fftw_output_norm2d_real_y=0.txt


Please select a case: """

#----------------------
# Hardcoded stuff
#----------------------

file_dict={}
file_dict['1'] = ('fftw_output_norm1d_fft.txt', '1d Fourier transform')
file_dict['2'] = ('fftw_output_norm1d_real.txt', '1d Full circle')
file_dict['3'] = ('fftw_output_norm2d_fft_x=0.txt', '2d Fourier transform, x=0')
file_dict['4'] = ('fftw_output_norm2d_real_x=0.txt', '2d Full circle, x=0')
file_dict['5'] = ('fftw_output_norm2d_fft_y=0.txt', '2d Fourier transform, y=0')
file_dict['6'] = ('fftw_output_norm2d_real_y=0.txt', '2d Full circle, y=0')


#------------------------
# Get case from cmdline
#------------------------

case = ''

def enforce_integer():
    global case
    while True:
        case = input(errormessage)
        try:
            int(case)
            break
        except ValueError:
            print("\n\n!!! Error: Case must be an integer !!!\n\n")
            sleep(2)

if len(argv) != 2:
    enforce_integer()
else:
    try:
        int(argv[1])
        case = argv[1]
    except ValueError:
        enforce_integer()

filename,title=file_dict[case]


#-------------------------------
# Read and plot data
#-------------------------------

k, Pk = np.loadtxt(filename, dtype=float, unpack=True)

fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#  ax.plot(k, Pk, label='power spectrum')
if case in ['1', '3', '5']:
    ax.plot(k, Pk, label='recovered wave', lw=3) # ignore negative k
    x = np.linspace(k.min(), k.max(), 1000)
    if case=='1':
        ax.plot(x, np.sin(2*np.pi*x), ':', label='expected wave', lw=3)
    if case in ['3', '5']:
        ax.plot(x, np.sin(x), ':', label='expected wave', lw=3)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel("k")
    ax.set_ylabel("F(k)")

if case in ['2', '4', '6']:
    # in this case: k=x, Pk=f(x)
    ax.plot(k, Pk, label='recovered original', lw=3) # ignore negative k
    N=1000
    plen=500
    dx=plen/N
    x = np.linspace(k.min(), k.max(), 1000)
    y = np.zeros(1000)
    ind = int(1.0/dx)

    if case=='2':
        y[ind] = -0.5
        y[-ind] = 0.5
    if case in ['4', '6']:
        y[ind] = np.sqrt(np.pi/2)
        y[-ind] = -np.sqrt(np.pi/2)

    ax.plot(x, y, ':', label='expected original', lw=3)
    ax.set_title(title)
    ax.set_xlabel("x")
    ax.set_ylabel("f(x)")

ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Comment: And why do you think it is a normalization issue? When the wavenumbers are wrong, it is not just normalization.

Comment: @VladimirF to all your questions: Mostly because I'm new at this. I changed the functions to `fftw_`, but the results stay identical. Only other thing I can think of is that I fundamentally misunderstand the FFTW conventions, which is why I explicitly wrote out what I expect it to calculate.

Comment: This probably has to do with the r2c c2r format when only half of the wavenumbers are stored. FFTW now provides some pictures which I don't remember seeing before http://www.fftw.org/fftw3_doc/Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data.html#Multi_002dDimensional-DFTs-of-Real-Data

Comment: A quick comment (whose bottomline is: in my experience, a signal composed of a single trigonometric function is enough to be sure that one normalizes `FFTW`'s transforms properly). FFTW really computes *a Fourier series*, i.e. the transform of a signal with a finite periodicity. Introducing Dirac distributions--and even worse, 2D Dirac distributions--and infinities is going to introduce some artificial subtleties compared to a real problem. Why not starting with a simpler signal? A cosine on a 10x10 grid is probably enough to start with.

Comment: Also:  `pi` is not double precision in your definition. Here is an easy `dp` version: `pi= 4._dp*atan(1._dp)`

Comment: @BenBoulderite because I need to make sure the normalisations are correct in both the forward and backward direction, since I'm having problems with it (https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/50007/correctly-scaling-power-spectrum-and-correlation-function-of-galaxies-from-mock)
I figured whether I get Dirac distributions in real or Fourier space doesn't make much difference in choice with which to start, since I transform forth and back. The infinities however I only wrote down for the complete expression of the continuous FT, I'm not actually calculating anything with infinities...

Comment: The normalisation of Fourier transforms does not exist: there are merely choices. The first step is really to write *your* convention of the *discrete* Fourier transform (DFT). Once you've done that, I stick to my point that very simple signals (in both spectral and physical spaces) are enough to check that you normalise the result given by FFTW so that to implement *your convention* correctly. I understand that there are no infinities in your computations, but the expression of continuous transforms on infinite intervals is not the simplest path toward a correctly normalized DFT.

Comment: Normally you would want to do the normalization in the inverse transform, not the forward transform. This is the most common convention because it makes it simpler to do things like convolution through the FFT. You found the normalization you need, `1/nm` (for `n` rows and `m` columns), i.e. divide by the total number of pixels. It seems to me that the only issue in this question is that you interpret the multi-dimensional frequency-domain result.